# How to change currency code abbrevation with currency symbol in Magento

Tags: magento, currency, symbols

I have a slight problem with Magento here.

If you look at this page

[MY DEMO PAGE](http://saneldesign.com/polapara/ponude/hrana-i-pice/vrhunski-obrok-za-dvoje-u-fast-food-pizzeriji-mutvak.html#.UzLxFM7yDcc)

You will see RED BUTON with title KUPI and price as 9 BAM.

BAM is my currency code, not my currency symbol. I need to replace this "BAM" with "KM".

On checkout everything is fine, all prices are in "KM" not in "BAM".

Code of this part (with button KUPI) is:

```
 <div class="pull-right" id="deal-show-vitals-buy">
                    <a onclick="submitform();" data-deal_id="<?php echo $_product->getId();?>" href="#"
                       data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-large btn-g font-large"
                       id="buy-button">
                        <strong>KUPI</strong> <?php echo $this->getPriceCurrency($_product->getPrice()); ?> </a>
                </div>
```

Problem is in this part of code, i think:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceCurrency($_product->getPrice()); ?>
```

Please, any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core helper ( Mage::helper('core') ) has a method in it which you can use to format the currency.

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice()) ?>
```

As an alternative, you are able to get the currency symbol as a stand alone option as well.

```
$symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
echo $symbol;
```

My recommendation is to use the first option (the core helper) since it is the primary purpose of using helpers.

**References**
[Magento Core Helper Documentation](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Helper_Data.html)

Comment: Thank you John, that was very kind from you. Per advice, I used first option, works like a charm. My gratitude